# Bullet character is oversized on android

Tags: android, css, font-size, bullet

I'm using the bullet character \25Cf as a pseudo-element in my menu. It displays fine on Chrome PC but on Chrome Android the character is way too big. All the other text on the page is correctly sized... Here is the markup:

The CSS:

```
.current-menu-item a:before {
    content: "\25Cf";
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    left: -15px;
    top: -3px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<li id="menu-item-76" class="current-menu-item"><a href="http://localhost:8080/wp12-fidusalaire/" aria-current="page">services</a></li>
```

I've tried setting the size in pixels or rem, with no apparent result...

Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

That unicode character just happens to be oversized on android - \2022 is more consistent across devices and is still a bullet